# docker push failed: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: docker, dockerhub

when I use `docker push` to push my images to docker hub, I will get error like this:

```
Post https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/lutaoact/docker-whale/blobs/uploads/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

or:

```
Head https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/lutaoact/docker-whale/blobs/sha256:ce3756df5cd31626b2664e9ac3713eec2585a64b7b31350c963328137b6f391d: dial tcp 54.172.138.33:443: i/o timeout
```

maybe `54.172.138.33` is blocked. 
How could i set proxy for the docker to access this ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker support to configure a proxy server, [doc](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/).

You can set environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` to set proxy. For example:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8123 docker pull hello-world
HTTPS_PROXY=https://127.0.0.1:8123 docker pull hello-world
```

You also can edit file `~/.docker/config.json` to configure proxy:

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "httpsProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs mostly when I don't have good internet. Check your internet connection. It will resolve the issue.

Also create a docker registry cache: https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/

Answer (score 0):

Change the docker mirror to your local area mirror,for example,In China,you can use Azure Mirror:

```
"registry-mirrors" : [
    "https://dockerhub.azk8s.cn"
  ]
```

like this:

[image]

until 2020-03,it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

for someone who still finds this can re-reun "docker push" command so that it will check for previously pushed layers if any layers are missing it will continue from that layer, it wont push from beginning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).